# sourcecode compilation in linux

Tags: c++, linux, compilation

I am not able to compile the source code for Verilog2C++ in centos 6.4 linux. Please download the sourcecode from here. Its pretty simple to download.

http://verilog2cpp.sourceforge.net/

I get the following errors when i run the make command

```
verilog.l:435: error: 'assert' was not declared in this scope
```

When i comment out all the assert statements. I run into these errors which I CANNOT FIX

```
Verilog.cc: In constructor 'moe::Verilog::Number::Number(const char*)':
Verilog.cc:224: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
Verilog.cc:230: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
Verilog.cc:245: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'
```

Below is the code snippet from Verilog.cc file

```
  Verilog::Number::Number(const char* text):
    text_(text)
  {
    static const char* BIN_NUM ="01XZ";
    static const char* OCT_NUM ="01234567XZ";
    static const char* HEX_NUM ="0123456789ABCDEFXZ";

    vector<char> bits;
    const char* ptr;

    ...

    char* idx;
    ptr =text+strlen(text)-1;
    for( ;*ptr!='\'';ptr-- )
      {
        switch( base )
          {
          case 2:
            idx =index(BIN_NUM,toupper(*ptr)); //THIS LINE CAUSES ERROR
            if( idx!=NULL )
              if( bits.size()<width )
                bits.push_back( *idx );
```

I am not able to fix this because of lack of C/C++ knowledge

Can you please help me compile and run the program successfully.

Comment: "Please download the sourcecode from here"  No, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your poisoning comment

Comment: My comment effected nobody reading this question.  They will decide to download that code or not.  This question on the other hand is nothing more than asking us to provide end-user support for a product that we didn't create.  You might think, "but somebody might know the answer and want to help."  That doesn't make this question any less off-topic.

Comment: If you can't say anything good, staying silent is not a bad option. This is not a commenting forum. Only constructive criticism is encouraged rather than subjective opinions

Comment: @user2065276 Hint: your question was downvotes 6 times already.  JohnDibling only expressed concisely what others are thinking.  At the very least you could have copied the offending code fragment into your question, alongside a pointer to the downloadable code.

Comment: By being critical of an off-topic question, I did say something good.  It just happened to not be in *your* best interests.  And that this question is off-topic isn't my *opinion* -- it is a fact reflected in this site's [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: feedback from fvu is taken into account. Thanks

Comment: John can you please direct me which is the best place to ask this question? and i shall do it. I am also mindful of my time and yours too

Comment: @user2065276 I extended your code fragment as the declaration of ptr is important.

Comment: I'm not sure if there *is* a StackExchange site where this would be on-topic, but if any are I would guess unix.stackexchange.com or askubuntu.com (obv not the latter since you're specifically not on ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks John for your comment. Kind Regards,

Comment: @user2065276: Since you are not familiar with C++ or with Linux, did you consider subcontracting the work, i.e. pay someone a few hours to get your problem solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the code is buggy, so new compilers refuse to compile it.

Edit the code and use a

```
const_cast<char*> (variablename)
```

to remove the constness of the variable.

Comment: Can you explain more and perhaps give an example? Thanks for your response though

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by compiling the code on an older machine with older version of gcc and then taking the executable to the new machine. It works just fine.

Thanks to Claudio's hint.